# prototypeで関数を追加した時に自インスタンスは参照できますか？

Tags: javascript, node.js

以下の様に、prototypeで追加したメソッドで、自インスタンスの参照方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
Date.prototype.hoge = () => {
  console.log(this);
};

var hoge = new Date();
hoge.hoge(); // why undefined
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！アロー関数と無名関数の違い勉強いたします！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アロー関数と無名関数を用途に応じて使い分けましょう。
今回の場面ではアロー関数を使うのは不適切です。

無名関数を使って、下記のようにすればできます。

```
Date.prototype.hoge = function() {
  console.log(this);
};

var hoge = new Date();
hoge.hoge();
```